# Undifined reference to libvlc

Tags: qt-creator, libvlc

Hi I want to buil a project with libvlc with qtcreator5.
I have include the library vlc

```
#include <vlc/vlc.h>
```

but when I want to compile I have this error :

```
/home/eid/Code/Joker/tests/VideoTest/player.cpp:26: error: undefined reference to 'libvlc_new'
```

Can anyone help me?

sry for my english

Comment: Have you made sure it's finding the library in the right place?

Answer (score 2):

you have to add something like this in your .pro

```
INCLUDEPATH += "../vlc" \
LIBS += "../libvlc_new.so" \
```

the include path is the way where there is the vlc headers , and libs where is your vlc lib
it must be a .so

Comment: I can't. I don't have 15 reputation :s